# How do I delete a key from a variable with two keys?

Tags: php, arrays

How do I delete a key from a variable with two keys?

```
<?php
$input = array("word1","word2","word3","word4","word5","word6","word7","word8","word9","word10","word11");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
$mixnames0 = $input[$rand_keys[0]].$input[$rand_keys[1]].$input[$rand_keys[2]].$input[$rand_keys[3]].$input[$rand_keys[4]].$input[$rand_keys[5]].$input[$rand_keys[6]].$input[$rand_keys[7]].$input[$rand_keys[8]];
$addtofi = $mixnames0;
```

$addtofi now have two keys, I want only one, how to delete one from it?
(No matter which one to delete, important is to delete a key)
Or a way to extract only one key from key de $addtofi

I've seen something like that:

```
unset($mixnames0[$rand_keys[1]]);
```

But I can not get it to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_rand($array, $num)` returns `$num` random keys out of `$array`. For reference take a look at documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

In your code array `$rand_keys` will be of length `2`, so `$rand_keys[2]`, `$rand_keys[3]` and so on are all undefined. Although your question is unclear, I think what you want to achieve is to pick one random word out of `$input` array and code for that should be:

```
<?php
  $input = array("word1","word2","word3","word4","word5","word6","word7","word8","word9","word10","word11");
  $addtofi = $input[array_rand($input, 1)];
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, has improved my code. Thank you very much :-)